# Count two sales opportunities with the same client and same close date as one

Tags: sql-server, count, powerbi

**Summary of my problem:**
Our company offers two software products (for simplicity we'll call them product A and product B).  In the past, when a client wanted to buy both products, the sales team would create a separate opportunity object for each product.  Both of these opportunity objects have the same client ID (unique identifier for each client) and same close date but a different opportunity ID (unique identifier for each opportunity object).

In the present time, if a client wants to buy both products, the sales person will only create one opportunity object containing both products.  This presents a challenge when comparing statistics from past years to the present as the past statistics are inflated to appear like 2 opportunities were closed when in reality it was one client buying the two products at the same time.

**Example in table data format:**
[**Simple example of data**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbZcc.jpg)

**What I am trying to achieve**

In either my SQL query or later in Power BI, I would like to count these old opportunities as one.  In other words, whenever an opportunity has the same client and same close date as another opportunity in the table, I want to count this once.

I attempted to flag this with a CASE statement unsuccessfully.  I also tried to nest a query within a join but ran into issues because my query already has 4 JOINS and 6 WHERE statements.  Any ideas?  If I need to provide more examples or details, please let me know.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column with the "main" opportunity id, then you can do a distinct count in Power BI on this column if you want only the "real" opportunities.  You can use the OVER clause for this:

```
SELECT *,MIN(opportunityId) OVER (PARTITION  BY ClientId,closeDate) as MainOpportunityId
FROM opportunities
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I needed, much appreciated.